# Zipping Weblogic JVM log files using log4j2.properties

Tags: logging, jvm, log4j, weblogic

Currenty I can see the weblogic jvm logs are getting generated under wl/appName/logs/. The need is to ZIP the jvm logs, as the size is getting huge. Can we do it using the log4j2.properties in the applicaiton. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 uses RollingFile appender to achieve this feature. Take a look at the [documentation](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-rollingfileappender-example/) for setup.

Comment: Thanks for the details you shared. But the issue here is: The log4j appender use to- rollover the file it has wrritten logs into. While the present scenario is - JVM logs are getting generated not using log4j but from weblogic. How can we use log4j to just compress the old files in .gz / other format. The JVM log file name is coming out to be like: wl_jvm_*.<processID>.log

Comment: If logs are really generated by WebLogic you can configure server logs to rotate and archive old files. Use the admin console and go to the server configuration. Log configurations are under tab Configuration/Logs.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using log4j API's? The current need is something like this. We want to handle the JVM logs using log4j configurations but not using existing weblogic admin configurations. Need some way using log4j only.

Comment: If you are using version 11g you can "force" weblogic to use log4j instead of jdk logging api. Read [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/WLLOG/config_logs.htm#i1014785) for that.
Recent versions (12c) does not allow to use log4j for weblogic system logging.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. It helped a lot on the analysis I was doing. 
Is there any reference / documentation citing that 12c does not allow use of log4j / log4j2?

Comment: Got the references from the oracle site: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES364